# why are aliases not getting executed?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

> Hello, I'm having an issue with aliases in discord.js the aliases don't work, I don't know why?

```
client.on('message', message =>{
    // Exit when the message from the bot
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (!client.commands.has(commandName)) return;

    const command = client.commands.get(commandName) || client.commands.find(cmd => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName));

    try {
        command.execute(message, args, commandName, client, Discord);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
    }
});
```

Comment: how do you assign the aliases? I personally do it in a different way, than the "recommended" way of discord.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t use aliases because you put

```js
if(!client.commands.has(commandName)) return;
```

This returns false if you try an alias, or anything else that isn’t in your `client.commands` keys. Remove this line and use this instead:

```
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();
const command = client.commands.get(commandName) || client.commands.find(cmd => cmd.aliases?.includes(commandName));
if(!command) return;
//...
```

This looks for the command *first* and then if no command is found, name or alias, it returns

Answer (score 0):

You check if the entered command exists like this:

`if (!client.commands.has(commandName)) return;`

So if the entered command is an alias, it will return. You would wanna do something like this:

```js
client.on('message', message => { // Setup the event listener
    // Exit when the message from the bot or is not a command
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/); // Define args
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase(); // Get the command name

    let command = client.commands.find(cmd => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName)); // Try to find the command by alias

    if (!command && !client.commands.has(commandName)) return; // The command doesn't exist

    command = client.commands.get(commandName); // If the command is not an alias, find it by name

    try {
        command.execute(message, args, commandName, client, Discord); // Attempt to execute the command
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
    }
});
```

First check if there are any aliases that match the entered command. If there are none, it will return undefined. Then we have an if statement to check if neither the aliases or the command are found and if so return. Otherwise use the normal command name to find the command.

Answer (score 0):

`if (!client.commands.has(commandName)) return;`
this line should be after the `const command = ...`
because `client.commands` is a collection with the commands, and all of the keys are the commands' names and not the aliases.